# Overlay an image (UIImageView) into photo

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

Is there a way to integrate a UIImageView when taking photos?

I can't seem to find a topic discussing this.

What I wanted to do is to have a UIImageView overlay on the preview. When the shutter is tapped, it should take the picture with the UIImageView embedded in it.

[image]

So here's where I am right now. The "test image" part will be made draggable on top of the preview view. I want to include that image with the image I'll be taking when I push the shutter button.

Is this possible? Or is there a better way?

I'm using AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer, AVCaptureSession and AVCapturePhotoOutput. I'm just putting the UIIMageView above the UIView where the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer is also a subview.

EDIT: Tested saving the UIView as an image, and it doesn't include the preview layer (only returns the UIView + UIImageView overlay).

Comment: Its not clear what you are trying to do please update your question with more detail description

Comment: I'll attach an image to describe what I want to do.

Comment: You can add star image as subview while camera is active or if you are using UIImagePickerController, then you can add stara view as overlay view. Once image is captured, and navigate to preview mode, place star imageview at same location as in camera screen. Once need to share/save image, then you need to add this star image as watermark at same location in image.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could add some more info regarding the current view hierarchy and how exactly you're capturing the image (are you using `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is at least two ways of doing this.

1) Capture photo from camera and add overlay image based on draggable image view position. This will produce best possible quality.

2) If you don't need photo quality you can use another solution - render draggable view layer in graphic context and video preview layer:

```swift
func takePhotoWithOverlay() -> UIImage? {
    let overlayImageView // UIImageView with overlay image
    let videoPreviewLayer // AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer

    guard let superview = overlayImageView.superview else { return nil }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(superview.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
    defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }

    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }

    videoPreviewLayer.render(in: context)
    overlayImageView.layer.render(in: context)

    return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Finally. I've actually arrived at the first conclusion, but I'll try the 2nd option you gave since photo quality is not of utmost importance and we actually downscale the image during upload.

Comment: Do you have an example for method 1) ?